# iptables logging for all except ICMP

Tags: linux, iptables, logs, firewall

I have `iptables` firewalls and its logging for all DROP packets or Deny. I want to tell it to no LOG any packet for ICMP protocol. How do i tell that

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [24:5541]
:DROPLOG - [0:0]
-A INPUT -s 108.34.21.45 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 210.23.72.22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 108.35.98.7 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 167.98.200.1 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 172.56.21.10 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 185.201.88.91 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROPLOG
-A DROPLOG -j LOG --log-prefix "DENY: " --log-level 6
-A DROPLOG -j DROP
COMMIT
```

Here is the log sample:

```
DENY: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:36:55:7a:3b:6c:00:31:d7:ba:a4:00:08:00 SRC=84.137.71.48 DST=108.101.99.137 LEN=88 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=118 ID=21684 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=3 CODE=3 [SRC=108.101.99.137 DST=192.168.2.102 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=21458 DPT=62936 LEN=40 ]
```

following stupid logs filling my disk... I want to tell `iptables` ignore ICMP. I don't want to use `limit` because i don't care of ICMP messges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you insert a

```
-A INPUT -p icmp -j DROP
```

before

```
-A INPUT -j DROPLOG
```

Drop the ICMP packets, then send the others to DROPLOG to get logged (and dropped).

Comment: you are the boss!!!